# Qlikview: How do I limit chart (straight table) lines to calculated values?

Tags: calculated-columns, qlikview

I have a problematic table, which is interconnected and goes out of memory often, but I've limited it to show 50 items, but now want to limit it to show only lines that one column calculated. The calculation - one price minus another one. I need to limit the lines so that the % or the value is less than 0 (meaning everything with -% or -<0 is acceptable).
Using a calculated dimension does not let me do an if function to accomplish this. The deduction does not work for some reason.

Any help?

Comment: This is possible with calculated dimensions. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39983623/1649780).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering by a calculated measure involving multiple fields in Qlik Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917942/filtering-by-a-calculated-measure-involving-multiple-fields-in-qlik-sense)

Comment: I think I understand and what you need to do is create all the expressions so that they are zero when your criteria is met. This is the place of the if() you mention. The dimensions will display so long as any 1 of the expression lines gives a non-zero value. So your expressions should look something like sum(if([]<0,expression,null()). Hope I have understood and that it makes sense. Otherwise I can create an example when I have more time

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I've tried calculated dimensions, however they only garble or re-sort the same data. I want to limit the data. I'm trying for example "if(dimensionX='-', 0, 1)", which does not work for calculated expressions. I'd like to limit it by the calculated value in a specific column. Which is calculated also - "dimensionz-dimensiony". Something like that. Qlik for some reason only offers to do calculated dimensions on actual data values, rather than what the program has calculated.

Comment: To clarify: I have a list, which has two sources. One source has products, origins, prices. I am comparing it to another list, the names are joined, other prices are being added. I've calculated the difference between sources for the products. NOW: I want to limit the merged list, where it makes sense, so that I know where the calculated difference is above 0%. I only care of the difference to one side. But my formula cannot limit the list based on a calculated column. Any other ways I can get around this?

Comment: Steps 4 and 5 of the answer I linked to are exactly what you describe as the things that solved your problem in the "answer" you happened to come up with yourself...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just edited the formula to "`=if(dimension='-' or dimension='0', null(), dimension)`". So the kicker was actually setting this all to "`null()`" so the "`Suppress When Value Is Null`" recognizes things to null.

This actually solves my problem in a different way, however the goal is the same. This skips the values where a calculation is impossible due to lack from one source.

**[UPDATE Jun-3rd-2017]:** **I figured out exactly what I needed.** *I just made the calculation on the script side and now a calculated dimension is actually restricting all of the values by the calculated dimension as was intended.*