# Qlikview: Restrict dynamic dimension via variables

Tags: set, business-intelligence, analysis, qlikview

I want to create a table which shows all person with a revenue in a specifc range. Persons that are not in the range need to be hidden/filtered.
The range is specified by two variables: `vNettoAb` and `vNettoBis`.

My idea is it to create a dynamic dimension with the following code:

1. `person_dbid`
2. `=if(((sum(invoice.value) <= vNettoBis) AND sum(invoice.nettosumme_value) >= (vNettoAb)), %person_dbid)`

My formula show an unspecific error, I can't figure out why. Is there a way to filter the persons with Set Analysis (e.g. with e({....}) or do you have any suggestions for my dynamic dimension?

Thanks a lot! I need help ... I already wasted 2 days and have no idea left. :-)

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39983623/1649780) which uses a slider in the place of your variables, but can be adapted to your situation. Steps 4 and 5 are key in ensuring the chart/table only displays the values in the range you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

`= count( {< invoice.value = {"<=$(vNettoBis)"}, invoice.nettosumme_value = {">=$(vNettoAb)"} > } 1 )`

Calculated dimensions are allowed but they will lead to performance issues in bigger data sets. QlikView creates "virtual" tables on the fly in the memory when calculated dimensions are used. Try to avoid them as much as possible and "control" the dimensions from expressions. Read more about it [here](https://community.qlik.com/blogs/qlikviewdesignblog/2014/04/08/calculated-dimensions)